# Chrome freezing Ubuntu 20

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, intel, freeze

I have seen similar issues with previous Ubuntu versions, and some that could solve or ease this activating GPU acceleration, but these don't work for me.

I'm using a Gen 10 Core i7 with an integrated Nvidia MX350, I don't know if they can contribute to the problem.

If I have too much tabs opened it just freezes the whole system. A big problem when working on multiple projects at a time.

Comment: "*freezes the whole system*" suggests swapping and lack of sufficient RAM to handle all those open tabs.

Comment: Besides what @user535733 stated above, Chrome is also a huge memory hog as is and doesn't handle memory management as well as other browsers like Firefox.

Comment: You never said what version of Ubuntu or how much ram you have. Each tab in Chrome takes more ram.

Comment: Gen 10 and 11 do benefiti from much newer kernels than the ones currently shipped with Ubuntu 20.04. And the Nvidia graphics needs proprietary drivers.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  so this is a Ubuntu Core 20 system? That system wasn't designed for desktop use, try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM and it crashes just around 20 tabs, nothing crazy. 
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: Some may argue with me, but maybe try setting your `vm.swappiness = 10` in your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and run `sudo sysctl -p` to activate it and see if that helps.  That adjusts the aggressiveness towards swap to be less aggressive.